# Powershell: Move Subfolders but Ignore Files in Root?

Tags: powershell

Got what I thought was a fairly straightforward question but after several hours of Googling I can't find an answer. Pretty sure Powershell is versatile enough to do this, I'm just not sure how to go code it up.

So basically, I have this:

- W:\ (root)
- Main Folder 1

  - Subfolder 1

    - Sub-Subfolder 1
    - Sub-Subfolder 2
    - Sub-Subfolder 3
    - File1.fil
    - File2.fil
    - File3.fil

All I'm trying to do is get Powershell to search Subfolder 1 and move Sub-Subfolders 1-3 (and their contents) into Subfolder 1, but ignore Files 1-3.

The syntax that I've worked up looks like this:

```
$source = "W:\Main Folder 1\Subfolder 1\"
$destination = "W:\Main Folder\"

Get-ChildItem $source -attributes D -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "$destination" -Force -Verbose
```

When I -WhatIf it it looks like it should work, but then when I try it I get the dreaded "cannot create a file when that file already exists" (basically it's saying that it can't create folders in Main Folder 1 with the same names as ones from Subfolder 1). I've got a -Force flag there and I'd have thought this would do the trick, but...here we are.

Any idea what to do to force it to move them? (I don't want it to delete the existing folder to move the new one though.)

Comment: The sub-subfolders are already inside subfolder1... Why try to move a folder to the location it already is? You cannot move files/directories onto themselves. Are you sure about your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do this code works.

```
$source = "G:\Test\A\FolderTwo"
$destination = "G:\Test\A"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory | 
    Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose
```

Verbose Output:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: G:\Test\A\FolderTwo\Folder2A Destination: G:\Test\A\Folder2A".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: G:\Test\A\FolderTwo\Folder2B Destination: G:\Test\A\Folder2B".
```

The 7 regular files in the Source Folder remained there. The Directories in the Source Folder and all their contents including Sub folders were moved.

Just make sure you have the Source & Destination directories defined correctly.
Note there is no need for the -Recurse switch as moving whole directories also moves their contents.

Edited to remove un-necessary quotes per mklelement0's comment below!

Comment: It appears to work but it's still giving me the error: "Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

Comment: That seems like it should work, but please don't needlessly enclose the variable references in `"..."`, so as not to potentially give rise to the misconception that `"..."` is needed in order to safely pass variable values as arguments: unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, this is _not_ required in PowerShell.

Comment: mklement0, thanks for point this out. I though they were necessary when a path might contain spaces. Another lesson learned!

Comment: Guys in a vacuum this would be working fine but in this case I'm still getting the  "Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists" error. This is happening because there are already folders with the same name in Main Folder 1. I'd be very grateful if someone would tell me how to get around that problem instead of repeating the same solution.

Comment: So you need to modify  your question to reflect this and what action is to be taken when conflicts arise, i.e. Directory (Replace, Ignore), File (Replace, Ignore). Hard to write code if you don't know the parameters.

Comment: If you'll look carefully at my initial post, below the code segment, I added this segment: "When I -WhatIf it it looks like it should work, but then when I try it I get the dreaded "cannot create a file when that file already exists" (basically it's saying that it can't create folders in Main Folder 1 with the same names as ones from Subfolder 1). I've got a -Force flag there and I'd have thought this would do the trick, but...here we are."

Answer (score 0):

This should get you further. Change the `"$($folder.name)-2"` to whatever you want to append the new folder names with.

```
$destination = "W:\Main Folder\"
$source = Get-ChildItem "W:\Main Folder 1\Subfolder 1\" -Directory

foreach ($folder in $source) {
    $folder | Move-Item -Destination $destination\"$($folder.name)-2"
}
```

Comment: Sorry but no, not looking to change the folder names either. If what I'm looking to do isn't possible, no sense wasting any more time on this. Thanks all.